# jQuery create DIV with dynamic ID and defined CSS attributes (which define look and position of that div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, dynamic

I have some basic code here.  It just creates a div element to a certain defined position, and the ID is not dynamic.

```
var i=1;
while (i<=6)
{
    jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: 'karta_back'
        // I don't know how to insert CSS here
    }).appendTo('#igrac1');

    ++i;
}
```

The problem is with dynamic ids.  With css, I don't know how to define the CSS inside that function.  For this example, I used the internal CSS that is defined somewhere in the document.  With the position, I suppose that cards need to be CSS absolute positioned to perform like i would like.

This is the result that I have with this simple code I wrote:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2849320/achieved.png

This is what i want to achieve:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2849320/want%20to%20achieve.jpg

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your question regarding how to create dynamic IDs or how to set the CSS for each card? Should each card have it's own dynamically created CSS or will they all be the same?

Comment: i need dynamic ids i think @Nicola Peluchetti resolved that in his answer, but i need also a css with some same atributes, like background image that would be the same for all created objects, and possition that would be different for all created objects..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly just, use the `style` attribute, you don't need a dynamic id:

```
var i = 1;
while (i <= 6) {
    jQuery('<div/>', {
        id: 'karta_back' + i, //this will add serial number to end of ID
        //this is a good starting point for what you're trying to accomplish
        style: 'position:absolute;margin-left:' + i * 20 + 'px;z-index:' + i;
     }).appendTo('#igrac1');

     i++;
}
```

So you can select them like:

```
$('#karta_back1', '#karta_back2'); //selects first two
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aU7dM/2/) example of it working, with a crappy card image.

Comment: well i need dynamic id so i can later easy access that object that i created under separated id , but this style you wrote is useful, i did't know it could be used like that to define css inside function.

Comment: Updated answer, for a 'dynamic' ID

Comment: this is the closest answer that i needed, and can you give me a clue how to overlap cards, because this method dont overlap them, its just makes spaces between cards (i think it has to do something with apsolute positioning and z-index but i havent tried to do that yet)

Comment: Updated answer with jsFiddle example, and changed `float:left` to `position:absolute`

Comment: thank you for the answer mate, i will investigate that jsFiddle example further more :) cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it something like this. Classes are a much better way of handling the styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ctsus/

```
var i = 1;
while (i <= 6) {
    var newId = 'karta_back' + i;
    $('<div/>', {
        id: newId,
        'class': 'card'
    }).appendTo('#igrac1');

    i++;
}
```

```
#igrac1 div.card { 
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    height: 150px; 
    width: 100px;
    background: lightblue;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Comment: class: 'card' results illegal usage

Comment: and btw i know how to define css inside <style tag> but that wanst my question... i was wondering how to define it inside jquery function that creates new object (div element with css atributes in this case)

Comment: you can't use `class` in a JS Object, it is a reserved word. you must quote it: `'class'`

Comment: @Chad - How come the fiddle works then? Found this list after some Googling - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: Ah, look at the section marked "Words reserved for possible future use" and read the notice there. `class` is listed under this heading, it states `Note: Prior to Firefox 5 (JavaScript 1.8.6), these keywords could be used when not in strict mode. This ECMAScript violation was fixed in Firefox 5.`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create dynamic id you could do (sorry i can't access your  images, a proxy is blocking me):

```
             var i=1;
            while (i<=6)
            {    
                 var newId = 'karta_back'+i;
                jQuery('<div/>', {
                    id: newId 
                    //i don't know how to insert css here

                }).appendTo('#igrac1');

                i++;
            }
```

if you need to access later those elements use an [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
 $('div[id^=karta_back]')
```

Comment: You can specify CSS like so `id: newId, style: "background: yellow; color: red;"`. Or even better I would use the `addClass` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to avoid writing all your css in a string, you could chain attributes and css after the creation of the element. an example could be:

```
$('<div>')
  .attr({
    id: "myID"
  })
  .css({
    position: "absolute",
    background-color: "blue"
  });
```